# How to link disaggregate data to aggregate data when aggregation adds 0/NULL values?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a table sensor_data in a PostgreSQL 9.6 database:

```
    Column     |            Type             |    
---------------+-----------------------------+
 id            | bigint                      | bigserial
 station_id    | integer                     | not null
 datetime_bin  | timestamp without time zone | not null (one minute resolution)
 category_a    | integer                     | not null
 category_b    | integer                     | not null
 sensor_data   | integer                     | not null
```

Indexes:

- "station_logs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id),
- UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (station_id, datetime_bin, category_a, category_b),
- btree (datetime_bin)
- btree (sensor_id)

If the value for a combination of `station_id, datetime_bin, category_a, category_b` is 0, there is no row. We're aggregating this data to 15 minute bins, and want to add in 0s to make averaging on the aggregated data more user-friendly. We also periodically need to refresh a month of data, so wanted to have deleting the disaggregate data cascade to aggregates based on it.

**Our current approach is the following, but I'd be curious to know if there is a better/more proper way.**

#### Current approach

Aggregate table

```
    Column     |            Type             |    
---------------+-----------------------------+
 id            | bigint                      | bigserial
 station_id    | integer                     | not null
 datetime_bin  | timestamp without time zone | not null (fifteen minute resolution)
 category_a    | integer                     | not null
 category_b    | integer                     | not null
 summed_data   | integer                     | not null (with 0s)
```

Disaggregate table

```
    Column     |            Type             |    
---------------+-----------------------------+
 id            | bigint                      | bigserial
 station_id    | integer                     | not null
 datetime_bin  | timestamp without time zone | not null (one minute resolution)
 category_a    | integer                     | not null
 category_b    | integer                     | not null
 sensor_data   | integer                     | not null (without 0s)
 aggregate_id  | bigint                      | FOREIGN KEY aggregate(id)
```

Zeroes crossover table

```
    Column     |            Type             |    
---------------+-----------------------------+
 one_minute_id |bigint                       | FOREIGN KEY one_minute(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 aggregate_id  |bigint                       | FOREIGN KEY aggregate(id)
```

Triggers

- when deleting from disaggregate, delete from aggregate with same aggregate_id
- when deleting from disaggregate, cascades to zeroes table with Foreign Key
- when deleting from zeroes table, delete from aggregate with same aggregate_id.

Comment: never even heard of "Disaggregate table"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want the TimeScaleDB extension with a hypertable and 15 min time buckets.

- https://www.timescale.com/

It's a free and open source project, like Pg. And it's actively developed.

- https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb

Comment: Sounds like a useful tool. We are unfortunately constrained in our infrastructure.